# How to use OnComplete?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a Javascript/AJAX function that send an email (using a PHP page).

The function is:

```
new Request({
    method: "post",
    data: this,
    onRequest: function() {
      $('amCallMeBackForm').empty().addClass('amCallMeBackWait');
      $('callback').setStyle('background', 'url(\'http://www.mysite.it/modules/mod_amcallmeback/assets/sfondo_callback.png\') no-repeat transparent');
      $('callback').setStyle('height', '73px');
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        $('amCallMeBackForm').removeClass('amCallMeBackWait');
        $('amCallMeBackForm').addClass('amCallMeBackSent');
        alert(response);
    }
}).send();
});
```

It works fine, but i cannot manage the response from PHP page, where i've this code:

```
<?php 
class modAmCallMeBackHelper
{

function send($params) {
    // Check for request forgeries
    JRequest::checkToken() or die( 'Invalid Token' );
            // get data
    $name =     JRequest::getVar('name', '');
    $rif =      JRequest::getVar('rif', '');
    $phone =    JRequest::getVar('phone', '');
    $uri =      JRequest::getVar('uri', '');

            // get module params
    $subject =  $params->get('mail_subject');
    $reciptient =   explode(',', $params->get('receipt_email'));
    $app =      JFactory::getApplication();
    $sender =   array($app->getCfg('mailfrom'), $app->getCfg('fromname'));

            // make email
    $Body = '<strong>Azienda:</strong> '.$name."<br />";
    $Body .= '<strong>Riferimento:</strong> '.$rif."<br />";
    $Body .= '<strong>Numero di telefono:</strong> '.$phone."<br />";
    $Body .= '<strong>Pagina da cui &egrave; stato richiesto il contatto:</strong> <a href='.$uri.'>'.$uri."</a>";

    $mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
    $mailer->setSender($sender);
    $mailer->addRecipient($reciptient);
    $mailer->setSubject($subject);
    $mailer->isHTML(true);
    $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mailer->setBody($Body);
    if ($name == '' || $rif == '' || $phone == '' || $name == 'Azienda' || $rif == 'Riferimento' || $phone == 'Telefono') {
    } else {
    $send =& $mailer->Send();
    }

    if ($send != true) {
      return 'no';
    } else {
      return 'ok';
    }
}

    }
    ?>
```

When alert(response) is displayed i can see the whole html code ( included) from the page, but I'm not able to show only the "return" from the PHP page.

What am I doing wrong?

You can check an example of my problem here: http://www.sevenit.it (check at the top right of the page after 3 seconds)

Thanks

Comment: I do not see anywhere in your code where you specify the path to the PHP script. Unless the path/url is hard-coded inside the code of `Request` object, the object might try to post to the `/` page which returns the HTML content of the home page as-is.

Comment: I think that's because it calls an internal Joomla handle page, that receive data. Anyway, form action is set to <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>. Do you think i should specify the url?

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(response.responseText);
```

would be the way to go i believe.

EDIT:
Or what you might be wanting to do is:

```
$('#amCallMeBackForm').html(response.responseText)
```

Not 100% sure what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you Matthew for your fast reply.

Both method are good for me! But if I set as you can suggest, i receive an alert containing "undefined".

And about my question, i try to make easier to understand. When i complete that form, i click on submit button, than all data from the form are send to the PHP page that sends and e-mail (or not if there's an error). That page returns "ok" or "no" if there are some errors. Now i would like to retrieve only that "ok" or "no" responses to display a custom message on the form panel.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you're probably going to want to change `return` to `echo`